# ¿Se puede ir desde una activity con canvas, a otra activity?

Tags: android, studio

Lo que quiero es ir de MainActivity a otra activity a traves de onTouchEvent pero no encuentro la manera y tampoco encuentro informacion.
Estoy haciendo un juego y lo que pretendo es que al final se pueda ir a otra activity, para mostrar estadisticas o información similar.

```
@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (x > 0 && x < anchoPantalla && y > 0 && y < 1000) {
                // Cambiar de activity
            }
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: Si estás en un activity *siempre* puedes ir a otra. Qué te impide lanzar un `startActivity(new Intent(NombreDeTuActivity.this, ActivityDestino.class))`?

Comment: Ya está solucionado. Yo tenía "class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity" con "setContentView(new GameView(this));" y la captura de los eventos dentro del GameView y así no podia usar el Intent. Ahora he sacado el onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) de GameView y lo he puesto en MainActivity y funciona todo. Me queda mucho por aprender. Gracias a todos.

Answer (score 0):

La mejor forma es preparar tu clase para que reciba el contexto en el constructor, de esta forma lo puedes usar para iniciar la Activity:

```
 public class MyClass{ 

     Context context; 

     MyClass(Context ctx){ 
        this.context = ctx; 
     } 
    

@SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float x = event.getX();
    float y = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            if (x > 0 && x < anchoPantalla && y > 0 && y < 1000) {
                // Cambiar de activity
               context.startActivity(new Intent(context, ActivityDestino.class)) 
              
            }
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
  }

}


}
```